# How do I fix this TypeError in Python concerning non-int and floats?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I'm working with **Python 3** on **Visual Studio Code** and the project I'm working on is to calculate the user's lunar weight after receiving their terrestrial weight, then output how their weight changes overtime given an increase and a period of time.

This is the error message I've received multiple times, no matter how many times I've re-code:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

This specifically happens whenever I use the input() and/or sys.stdin.readline() functions, but all of the pertaining variables are integers or floats, whether or not I try to convert them to floats by using the float() function around my inputs.

---

Here is my code:

```
# this programs converts your terra weight to your lunar weight, then it takes increase over a period of time

# error whether I use float() or not
terraWeight = float(input("Terra Weight: "))

ask = input("Is this in LBS or KG? ")

# converts pounds to kilograms
# 2.204... is used to convert lbs to kgs
if ask == "lbs" or "LBS":
    initial = terraWeight / 2.2046223302272

# didn't need this, but assignment error popped up
x = 0

# or replace input() with sys.stdin.readline()
increase = input("Increase: ")
period = input("Period: ")

# gets lunar weight over time
def lunarWeight():
    global increase
    global period
    global x
    global initial

    print("Earth Weight = %s kgs." % terraWeight)
    year = 0
    lunarWeight = initial * 0.165
    print("Moon Weight = %s kgs. \n" % lunarWeight)
    postIncrease = lunarWeight * increase
    for x in range(0, period):
        year += 1
        lunarWeight += postIncrease
        print("Year %s = %s kgs." % (year, lunarWeight))

lunarWeight()
```

The terminal directs to the this section of my code:

```
postIncrease = lunarWeight * increase
```

Which is on line 28. I'm not sure what the problem is, and I tried debugging but I still get the same error messages. I saw other posts with the same problem but they had problems using lists, which I'm pretty sure I'm not using. Any advice please?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8axT4.jpg)

Comment: ```increase``` is a string, cast it to an int or float

Comment: `if ask == "lbs" or "LBS":` will always be considered true.  It's parsed `(ask == "lbs") or "LBS"`.  You should do `ask in ("lbs", "LBS")` instead.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi I then get this error message: `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: @TenajaYoung then you are casting it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should write this lines as:

```
increase = float(input("Increase: "))
period = int(input("Period: "))
```

period is used in `range()` so it should be integer

Comment: I received this error message after debugging: `'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: have you cast both the period and increase variables?

Comment: @TenajaYoung period should be in int

Comment: Oh, I have it now. I casted period as a float instead of an integer. Thanks!